# Prevent from leaving web application and redirecting to any other link

Tags: javascript, web, frontend

```
const adminLogOut = document.getElementById("adminLogOut");

adminLogOut.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.alert("Are You sure You want to leave?");
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are You sure You want to leave?"
}
```

The code above is going to prevent from logout and redirection. By redirection I mean leaving my web application stored on my local machine and run in Firefox. E.g. when I want to click on any bookmark in my browser, then .onbeforeunload function should prevent from leaving my application, but it works only when I want to leave the page which this JS code belongs to.
Would You give any advice?

Comment: You cannot prevent a user from leaving your site.

Comment: What about alert window appearing when someone wants to send an email without a subject or a text? Does it not work in this way in web apps?

Comment: Well sure, you can put up an `alert()`, but ultimately a user can just close the whole browser or turn off the computer (or tablet or whatever).